# Why does my Azure web app stop accepting requests (or not responsive)?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've been trying to find what's wrong with my web app on Azure. The web app service acts as an endpoint to my chatbot and every hour or so the number of request dropped significantly and it seems the service stopped (CPU time dropped to < 1s in what usually few mins when running normally)?.

How come my api app service suddenly dropped so much requests? Usually from 200+ per minute to lowly 10-20 requests per minute.
This can be resolved by simply restarting the server and it seems the server accepting requests again.

I try to find log where it goes wrong but no 500 or 4xx status code from the log. HTTP queue is also fine. In fact if I test my endpoints, they seem to be running just fine. So it's either :
1. My chat app somehow isn't sending requests to my endpoint
2. My server is somehow refusing all the requests from my chat app.

I'm at my wits end trying to find out what makes my server not responding or not getting requests.

Any idea what might be the cause? How do I track the problem?

Comment: Have you turned on Web Server Logging for your Web App?

Comment: yes, and I don't see any problem in it either or what signs in the log that I should look for?

Comment: I was curious to see if you see a steady stream of HTTP requests that you are expecting. I figured if you're actually seeing the HTTP requests coming into the server, you could then step up a level to see if your web app is seeing the requests. 
What pricing tier and SKU is your App Service?

Comment: well that is the thing, the stream of http requests stops or at least dropped significantly! 
It's either the chat API doesn't send requests to my endpoint or my endpoints simply refuses requests from that chat API.

my App Service pricing tier is Basic 1, but I've changed pricing tier and the problem remains. My performance monitor says I only uses 5% of CPU and 40% of memory.

Comment: Similar problem:I have an intensive I/O app that is proxying video content from a 3rd party to web. It works well at a rate of 8 clients each with 720p streams and after 5 minutes or less it suddently drops refusing any new connection for the next 5 minutes. I increased the connection pool size, I decreased the timeout of the HttpClient involved in the proxy operation to 2sec.. same behaviour?!
It's a P1V2 web app (210ACU and 3.5Gb). My process memory doesn't exceed 800Mb whereas the CPU is keeping low. 
Any ideas would be highly appreciated?! Is Azure a scam?! That machine is $100/month